# How to produce a complete HTML document using markdown?

Tags: html, css, markdown, syntax-highlighting

We can process the file `code.md` containing

````
Here is our first program.

```python
s = "Hello, World!"
print s
```
````

using

```
markdown2-2.7 -x fenced-code-blocks code.md > code.html
```

to produce the HTML

```
<p>Here is our first program.</p>

<div class="codehilite"><pre><code><span class="n">s</span> <span class="o">=</span> <span class="s">&quot;Hello, World!&quot;</span>
<span class="k">print</span> <span class="n">s</span>
</code></pre></div>
```

But then it's necessary to add `html`, `head`, and `body` tags as a postprocess, in addition to linking to a [css stylesheet](https://github.com/richleland/pygments-css) for syntax highlighting.

Is markdown2 really meant for this kind of workflow, or can the postprocess be incorporated a bit more seamlessly (without, for example, wrapping with an additional script)?

I am using `markdown2` and `pygments` installed on OS X through:

```
sudo port install py27-markdown2
sudo port install py27-pygments
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most [implementations](https://github.com/markdown/markdown.github.com/wiki/Implementations) of Markdown (including the original Perl implementation), only output an HTML fragment which you are then expected to pass to a template or otherwise wrap in an HTML `<body>`. If you search around, there are a few implementations that may include a feature to optionally output an entire document, but they are rare. [Pandoc](http://pandoc.org/README.html#templates) is probably the most prominent one, but that is also a lot more than a Markdown parser.

If you want to continue using the implementation to already have from the command line, the following should work (where `head.html` and `foot.html` contain everything before and after the Markdown fragment respectively):

```
cat head.html > code.html
markdown2-2.7 -x fenced-code-blocks code.md >> code.html 
cat foot.html >> code.html
```

Note that the `>>` operator appends to the end of a file rather than overwriting it.

Of course, this will not give you a `<title>` in your `<head>` and that, I expect, is why Markdown does not officially offer this as a feature. It is also why a templating system is generally preferred.

So to answer your question, yes, with a few rare exceptions, you are expected to write a script to wrap Markdown to get full HTML documents.